# Symfony2 ACL implemented as a service?

Tags: symfony, acl

I'm using ACL accross a few controllers, and was wandering whether there is a "clean" way to use ACL without writing the same code over and over again.

The ACL code I'm talking about is

```
// creating the ACL
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($comment);
$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

// retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
$securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

// grant owner access
$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

from [the sf2 cookbook.](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/acl.html)

Would a good idea be to implement this code as a service, and then extend it if needed, and use it instead of writing the same code in each controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should wrap that within a service. Not only will it cut down on the amount of code you need to copy & paste, but since it will be a service you can inject it into any other service and still take advantage of the ACL system.

Comment: And in fact, [I've already done it](https://github.com/Problematic/ProblematicAclManagerBundle)

Comment: @Problematic Thanks for the link, checking it out now.

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing. Nice bundle.